# Run a script as root during boot and display in the default linux terminal?

Tags: linux, boot, init-script, init.d

Here's how I configured my kickstart system initialization script (this is a kickstart conf script snippet):

```
...

%post --log=/root/ks-post.log --interpreter /bin/bash

cd /root
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 -O "https://mysecurewebsite.net/init-script7.sh"
cp init-script.sh /etc/init.d/initializesystem
chmod +x /etc/init.d/initializesystem
[ ! -d /etc/rc.d ] && echo "/etc/rc.d/ not present, creating dir." && mkdir /etc/rc.d
[ ! -d /etc/rc.d/rc3.d ] && echo "/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/ not present, creating dir." && mkdir /etc/rc.d/rc3.d
ln -s /etc/init.d/initializesystem /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S30initializesystem

%end
```

This works great and runs in the background unattended upon first boot after the OS installation.

However I would like to make this even more friendly by letting the default bootup tty to display the stdout of this `initializesystem` script. Currently I have the script writing its progress to a log file, and I have to log in as root and `tail -f` the log file. I'd like to still be able to do this if I want, but I want to know if it is possible to also just have it automatically show the output without requiring me to log in.

One thing to note is that I don't want to make the system completely uninteractive. For instance I would like to be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login to do some administration while this script proceeds.

I would also prefer it if a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> wasn't able to kill this particular script while it runs, though I suspect that can be an easy thing to set up for handling the SIGINT, so forget that I mentioned it.

Is this possible? Using Centos 7 here.

Comment: Going off what I know ... seems like maybe using `tee` to pipe the output of the script to `/dev/tty1` or some such might be my ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicate yourself, as root you can just write things to `/dev/tty1`.

If your script does write to stdout you can use:

```
yourscript | tee -a /your/log/file > /dev/tty1
```

if the script directly writes to the log file things are not so easy, you would have to follow the log file and display new content. In that case it is probably easier to change the script to use some `print` routine in which you can easily double the output.

There is no way this can be stopped by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, not even if you have logged in first on the console, as there is no way for your shell to know where to sent the interrupt.

Depending on your startup preferences, whether you have a graphical login or not, you might want to use `/dev/tty2` as not to clobber the first screen. 
You should also consider starting the log with a newline so the first text doesn't appear after the

```
machinename login:
```

prompt that is at the top of the screen.

I don't think there is a way to scroll back on the console you have been writing to in this way, but that might not be important.

Comment: Yeah I figure the standard use case will involve glancing at the screen (if connected) without requiring any keyboard input. If I do want to actually use the machine while it runs I can just `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and go from there.